# jQuery delay queue function not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to perform an action after my $.get function completes, but the code that I have below is not working.  Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
$.get('assets/php/paymentaccounts.php', function(data) {
             $('#PaymentAccounts').html(data);
          }).delay(400).queue(function(next){
                var config = {
                    '.chosen-select'           : {},
                    '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
                    '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
                    '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
                    '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
                }
                for (var selector in config) {
                    $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.get()` returns a promise, it doesn't have `queue` method.

Add the queue inside the callback, attached to the jQuery object, which has a `queue` method

```
$.get('assets/php/paymentaccounts.php', function(data) {
     $('#PaymentAccounts').html(data).delay(400).queue(function(next){
        var config = {
                '.chosen-select'           : {},
                '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
                '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
                '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
                '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
        }
        for (var selector in config) {
            $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
        }

        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: No!! You're never calling `next()` (nor `dequeue()`), stalling will ensue!

Comment: @adeneo, your fiddle works because your code and *only* your code is queueing behavior (and only once). The `next` argument your queued function takes has a purpose -- to be called in order to progress to the next method in the queue. Not calling it means breaking the queue for others (and possibly yourself) down the line. [Relevant documentation](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I know how it works, but there's no need to call `next` when there's nothing more queued, but if it makes you happy, I'll add it as it doesn't matter.

Comment: @adeneo, *I know how it works, but there's no need to call next when there's nothing more queued, but if it makes you happy, I'll add it as it doesn't matter.* You're aware that Javascript on the browser is basically a huge, distributed environment that tries its best to be collaborative, right? Then why would you suggest code that potentially breaks other code in the same environment and dismiss the solution as "making me happy"? ;)

Comment: Because in this case it doesn't matter, there's nothing else added to the queue, and there's no need to call `next`, the only possible reason would be if another queue somehow was attached to the same element elsewhere in the code, and that wouldn't really matter either, as you'd generally call `dequeue` on the last queue added to keep the order, and then `next` still wouldn't have to be called, it's really only useful if you have chained queues.